# Convert Dates PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

All,

I am migrating a few processes from SQL Server (SQL) to ParAccel (PostgreSQL).
One of the processes I have is currently using the following conversion.

```
Select convert(datetime,convert(varchar,MAX(getdate()), 101),101)
```

After you run this query, you get: 2014-05-07 00:00:00.000

I found a function in postgresql that could do this job. The function is:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', getdate());
```

When you execute that query, you get the following:  5/7/2014 12:00:00 AM

Is there a way in PostgreSQL that you could get the same results as in SQL. SO I want to get `2014-05-07 00:00:00.000`

Also, how can I just get the date, instead of the whole `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: getdate() is not a (standard) function in PostgreSQL, are you sure about your example? I haven't seen date_trunc() using this format either, it's just truncating data and not formatting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would to get date from timestamp, just do

```
postgres=# select current_timestamp::date;
    now     
────────────
 2014-05-07
(1 row)
```

There are two ways

- preferred - use a to_char function

  ```
  postgres=# select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mm:ss.ms');
          to_char         
  ─────────────────────────
  2014-05-07 19:05:52.537
  (1 row)
  ```
- or with datestyle config variable

  ```
  postgres=# set datestyle TO ISO;
  SET
  Time: 0.353 ms
  postgres=# select current_timestamp;
                now              
  ───────────────────────────────
   2014-05-07 19:12:44.236758+02
  (1 row)

  Time: 0.406 ms
  postgres=# set datestyle TO GERMAN ;
  SET
  Time: 0.565 ms
  postgres=# select current_timestamp;
                 now               
  ─────────────────────────────────
   07.05.2014 19:12:51.781772 CEST
  (1 row)

  Time: 0.700 ms
  ```

[related postgresql doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/functions-formatting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `to_char` function to format date/time values as text (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html).

If you're only interested in the date part, cast the timestamps to `date` type.

To change the default date appearance, you can set:

```
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
```

either in your session, or globally through postgresql.conf